# how do I move my cloned repository to another directory in putty

Tags: git, github

like right now, I have created a directory with my current directory path using mkdir. Now I want to move my cloned repository to the new directory. How do I achieve that?

I tried new_dir/old_dir but that resulted in "No such file or directory"

Comment: Try the `mv` command

Answer (score 0):

For just copying we could use

```
cp -r source_path destination_path
```

For completely moving we can use

```
mv source_path destination_path
```